# Specifying how script should be executed in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm working on Django project and I want to run a script that I wrote for quick prototyping. Say the script is named 'prototype.py'.

In terminal I can execute it by doing `python manage.py shell < prototype.py`

However, I would like to do this not through terminal, but directly through my IDE (PyCharm), is it possible?

I.e. run `python manage.py shell < some_script.py` when I press `Ctrl + Shift + F10` .

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into [PyCharm External Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/external-tools.html)

Essentially you can have PyCharm kick things off in its console. `File | Settings | Tools | External Tools | '+'`. You can play around with the top bit, but for the sake of this lets just say `Name = foo`, `Group = bar`, `Description = foobar`, and check all the boxes. For `Program` put `python`. In `Parameters` put `manage.py shell < some_script.py`. For `Working directory:`, depends on what you want. The `Insert macro...` button is pretty useful though.

I'm not sure if it will handle the `<` or `shell`, but worth a try. If they don't work there may be some way of restructuring your command to get it to work. For instance maybe adding that line to a "shell script" and kicking the shell script off from PyCharm.

You can run it from the `Tools | bar | foo` drop down menu. By just using it a couple times in a row PyCharm will ask if you want to make it a `Keymap`. Or you could do it [manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) `File | Settings | Keymap | External Tools`